# OnNestedScroll value not changing when scrolling

Tags: java, android

I am trying to create a behaviour for a `BottomNavigationView` that is supposed to dissappear when the user is scrolling down, the solution is supposed to work like the Google Material Design Guideline. And the issue I am having is that the variable `dyConsumed` in `OnNestedScroll()` remains unchanged and at 0 despite that the user is currently scrolling and the function is entered. What is causing dyConsumed to remain unchanged and why doesn't the value change on scrolling up or down?

Heres the behaviour of the `BottomNavigationView`:

```
public class BottomNavigationViewBehaviour extends CoordinatorLayout.Behavior<BottomNavigationView>
{

    private int height;

    @Override
    public boolean onLayoutChild(CoordinatorLayout parent, BottomNavigationView child, int layoutDirection)
    {
        height = child.getHeight();
        return super.onLayoutChild(parent, child, layoutDirection);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onStartNestedScroll(@NonNull CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout, @NonNull BottomNavigationView child, @NonNull View directTargetChild, @NonNull View target, int axes, int type)
    {
        return axes == ViewCompat.SCROLL_AXIS_VERTICAL;
    }

    @Override
    public void onNestedScroll(@NonNull CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout, @NonNull BottomNavigationView child, @NonNull View target, int dxConsumed, int dyConsumed, int dxUnconsumed, int dyUnconsumed, int type)
    {
        if (dyConsumed > 0)
        {
            slideDown(child);
        }
        else if (dyConsumed < 0)
        {
            slideUp(child);
        }
    }

    private void slideUp(BottomNavigationView child)
    {
        child.clearAnimation();
        child.animate().translationY(0).setDuration(200);
    }

    private void slideDown(BottomNavigationView child)
    {
        child.clearAnimation();
        child.animate().translationY(height).setDuration(200);
    }
}
```

And here is the XML file for the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <include layout="@layout/navigation_toptoolbar"/>

        <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="56dp"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
        <include layout="@layout/navigation_bottom"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Are you setting the behavior on anything? You can set in on a view in xml like this `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"`

Comment: Yea just tried setting it on the nestedscrollview but it didnt work!

Comment: You need to set the behavior on the bottom navigation view because you define its behavior, not the scroll views.

Comment: I am doing it in the OnCreate() function of the activity like this:          `CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) mBottomNavigation.getLayoutParams();     
        layoutParams.setBehavior(new BottomNavigationViewBehaviour());`

Comment: I think that the issue might be that the `NestedScrollView` is not actually scrolling, and is therefore not registering any y-movement. Could this be the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is now solved. The problem was that a fragment with a `GridView` was loaded into a `NestedScrollView` which apparently interferes with the scroll functionality. Instead of a `GridView`I implemented a `RecyclerView` with a `GridLayoutManager` in the fragment being loaded. Now it works perfectly!